# Can "Insert Trigger For Each Row After Each Statement" use index with the newly added values?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, indexing

I am using Postgres 9.3.
I just added a trigger to a table.
It is an after insert trigger which is executed for each row after each statement.
I coded the trigger function assuming the index of the same table contains the newly added rows.
If this is not true, mass inserts will slow down significantly.
I google it a bit but couldn't find an answer.

So, to sum up my questions is after a statement, is index updated before or after the "after insert trigger for each statement" in Postgres 9.3?

Here is the trigger definition I've used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON table_name
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_funtion();
```

Comment: Please show us the trigger definition the trigger function and the `create table` statement.

Comment: This is a hard question. It is also irrelevant. Your function does not depend on the presence of an index, or a row in that index.

Comment: I've added the trigger definition however I don't see the point of adding the table and the function in order to answer the question. In the function I've executed several queries and one of them depends on (hopefully uses) the index of the same table.

Comment: I guess that @a_horse_with_no_name is afraid of unlimited recursion. And so am I ...

Comment: The **function** is important because that's where the actual *processing* is done. And any performance problem with the trigger is going to be visible in the *function* not the definition

Comment: I just want to learn if index is updated before or after the "after trigger". How is this related with the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AFTER` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` will see that row in the table. For that to happen reliably the row must have already been added to any indexes. So the index has been updated.

However, if you attempt to modify the table that caused the `AFTER` trigger to be fired within the `AFTER` trigger, this usually results in an infinite loop and an error. It is rarely the correct thing to do.

Usually when you're trying to do that, you actually want a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies the row before it is saved.

If you need to modify some other row in the same table, that often suggests a data model problem. You should very rarely, if ever, need to modify one row in a table using a trigger when a different row is modified.

Comment: Is this also true for an AFTER trigger FOR EACH STATEMENT? I am not changing or modifying the table or any other data. I am just checking if it is consistent and if not raising an exception.

Comment: @araqnoon Yes. Same for statement level. An after statement trigger that couldn't see the new rows would be pretty useless. If you aren't modifying the table an after trigger is just what you want.